# SQL Server take long to respond with nodejs

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, t-sql

I used SQL Server as backend and node express as web server to make api's.

One api returns 10 results in 400ms, that is ok.

After some time, that api takes 7 to 10 seconds to respond with the same data.

Then I checked SQL Server and ran the same query on it, it takes 7 seconds for data display at first time.

Second time around, it takes 300 ms, after that the api returns the data within 400ms.

My question is: why does it takes 7 seconds to run the SQL query?

When I directly hit SQL Server, then the api responds within 400ms.

Why this?

This is my query:

```
    SELECT Max(ord.code)         code, 
       Max(os.orderstatus)   orderstatus, 
       Max(cus.altercode)    altercode, 
       Max(cus.NAME)         NAME, 
       Max(cus.mobileno)     mobileno, 
       Max(ord.createdonutc) createdonutc, 
       Count(otr.ordercode)  noofitems, 
       Max(cus.appid)        appid 
FROM   orders ord 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orderstatus os 
                    ON ord.code = os.ordercode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN customers cus 
                    ON cus.code = ord.customercode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN order_tr otr 
                    ON otr.ordercode = ord.code 
WHERE  os.orderstatus = 'PENDING' 
GROUP  BY otr.ordercode 
ORDER  BY code DESC
```

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here for somebody to be able to provide an answer. It could be locking, it could be parameter sniffing, it could be suboptimal execution plans....the list could go on and on. However, if you can provide the actual execution plans from when it works well and when it doesn't that would probably help. Table definitions including indexes, the actual queries....all the things you would need to be able to help.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60180/52607